# Cannot specify height and width correctly while using rotation = 270 in Seekbar Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am having trouble specifying height and width in vertical seekbar, android. I have specified the rotation equal to 270.

**Case 1:**

Width=300dp and Height=wrap_content

I get both height and width equal to 300dp.

**Case 2**

Width=wrap_content height=300dp

I get height equal to wrap_content and width equal to 300dp.

So my question is how do we specify height and width correctly while using rotation = 270.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.puzzleup.ScrambleActivity">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:max="7"
        android:rotation="270" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still facing similar problems with rotating seekbars atm

Comment: 8 years after still fighting with this problem.

Answer (score -2):

i know it's late but maybe this can still help you.

just made an article about this : 
http://www.mcfly-development.net/#/article/read/5

to resume, the vertical seekbar is not really working because android setup with and height before doing the rotation. 
maybe this can help

Comment: The website is no longer available. Can you summarize the solution here?